# Poincare' s inequality for vectorfields on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, inequality

Let $\mathbb{S}^2$ be the standard 2-sphere, and let $V$ be $\mathcal{C}^1$ vectorfield on it.
I'd like to understand if it is true that there exists $C > 0$ such that, for all such $V$, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{S}^2}|\nabla V|^2 \mbox{d}\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^2}\geq C \int_{\mathbb{S}^2}|V|^2 \mbox{d}\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^2},
$$
where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection associated to the standard metric, and $\sigma_{\mathbb{S}^2}$ is the standard volume form.

My heuristic reasoning was the following: usually, for a Poincare' estimate on functions, you need either some condition on the support or on the integral mean of the function. Here, by the Hairy Ball Theorem, $V$ is "pinned" to be zero at one point, hence I wonder if this is sufficient to say something.

In case it worked, I would also be interested in understanding if such an inequality holds for some subset of $H^1$-vectorfields on the sphere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it will be easier to work with one form. Let $\alpha$ be the one form dual to $V$, defined by

$$\alpha(X) = g (V, X). $$

Then

$$\int_S |\nabla V|^2 ds = \int_S |\nabla \alpha|^2 ds = \int_S g(\alpha, \nabla^* \nabla \alpha) ds$$

where $\nabla^*$ is the adjoint of $\nabla$, locally given by 
$$(\nabla^* \beta)_i = - g^{jk}\nabla_j \beta_{ki} $$

By the Bochner identity,

$$\Delta_d \alpha = (dd^* +d^*d)\alpha = \nabla^*\nabla \alpha + g^{jk}R_{ij}\alpha_k, $$

In our case, $R_{ij} = g_{ij}$ and so $g^{jk}R_{ij}\alpha_k = \alpha_i$ and

$$g(\alpha, \nabla^*\nabla \alpha) = g (\alpha, (\Delta_d - 1)\alpha).$$

So we want to know if $\Delta_d - 1$ is positive. Using the fact in:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57749/laplace-derham-operator-for-1-forms-on-the-sphere

The spectrum on one form is the same as the spectrum on functions (except the constant function as $df = 0$), and it is known that $\lambda_1 = 2$. Thus we have

$$\int_S |\nabla V|^2 ds \geq \int_S |V|^2 ds . $$

**Remark** The Bochner identity that I was using can be found in p.221 of this book:
http://www.amazon.ca/Riemannian-Geometry-Sylvestre-Gallot/dp/3540204938

(The calculation is eignevalue for Laplacian on spheres can also be found in this book).

The set of eigenfunctions actually forms an orthonormal basis for $L^2(M)$ when $M$ is compact. The reason is that the smallest eigenvalue can be found by minimizing

$$E(f) = \frac{\int_M |\nabla f|^2 dS}{\int_M|f|^2 dS}$$

among all nonzero $f\in W^{1, 2}(M)$ and in general the $n$-th eigenvalue is the infimum of $E(f)$ where now $f$ is the set of all $W^{1, 2}(M)$ orthogonal to the first $(n-1)$-th eigenfunctions. From this construction it is clear that the eigenfunctions are dense in $W^{1, 2}(M)$,thus also dense in $L^2(M)$.

**Another remark** Let's me briefly explain the proof in the first link. First of all, as $\Delta * = *\Delta$, $f$ is an eigenfunction for the scalar $\Delta$ if and only if $*f$ is an eigenform for $\Delta$ (on two forms). Since $** = \pm id$, the eigenvectors for $\Delta$ on two forms are the same as that of the scalar $\Delta$. Now we use the Hodge decomposition:

$$\Omega^1(\mathbb S^2) = \ker \Delta \oplus Im (d) \oplus Im (d^*) =  Im (d) \oplus Im (d^*) \  \ \ \ \text{as  }H^1(\mathbb S^2) =0,$$

Thus all one forms $\alpha$ are of the form $\alpha = df + d^*(* g)= df \pm * dg$ for some functions $f, g$. From here one see that $\Omega^1(\mathbb S^2$ is also generated by eigenform of the form $df$ and $*dg$.

(It is also in general true that for any compact $(M, g)$, the eigenforms of $\Delta$ forms a complete orthonormal basis for the space of $H^1$ eigenforms)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to ask a few clarifications. Could you please state the Bochner identity that you are using? Also, do you need to prove that the eigenvectors of the De-Rham operator constitute an $L^2$-complete orthonormal system?

Comment: @second: I have made an edit, please have a look.

Comment: Is it immediate that, if the scalar eigenfunctions of the De Rham operator constitute a complete and orthonormal basis in $H^1$, also the one-forms which are eigenvectors of the De Rham operator are a complete and orthonormal basis for the relative $H^1$ space of sections?

Comment: Please see the edit again @Second

Comment: Question: do we get anything if instead of the sphere we have a surface with a hyperbolic metric? I guess the question boils down to the spectrum of the Laplace-deRham operator on one forms in that case, which I have no clue about.