# Reference for the spectrum of the Bochner Laplacian on the 2-sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, laplacian

I am looking for a reference for the spectrum of the Bochner Laplacian on $S^2$.

Comment: Do you mean the Laplacian on functions or do you also want the action on 1, 2 forms?

Comment: I'm looking for the eigenvalues of $\nabla^*\nabla$, so the action is on vector fields.

Comment: [Highly Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1040985/poincare-s-inequality-for-vectorfields-on-the-sphere/1041048#1041048): Everything reduces to the calculations of Laplacians on functions.

Comment: Ok, so collecting form various posts:
(1) $\nabla^*\nabla = \Delta_d - 1 = dd^* + d^*d - 1$.
(2) $\Delta_d df = \lambda df$, $\Delta_d \ast df = \lambda \ast df$ if $\Delta f = \lambda f$.

From (1), the eigenvalues of $\nabla^*\nabla$ are those of $\Delta_d$ shifted by 1, and from (2) the eigenvalues of $\Delta_d$ are those of $\Delta$ (the scalar Laplacian) with double multiplicity.

Combining everything, it seems the answer should be $k(k+1)-1$ , for $k \geq 1$, with multiplicity $2(2k+1)$. Makes sense?

Would be nice to have a reference from a book. Perhaps it appears as an exercise?