# Poincaré's inequality for vector fields on a surface

Tags: analysis, riemannian-geometry, curvature, integral-inequality, geometric-inequalities

$\newcommand{\Ric}{\text{Ric}}$
Let $M$ be a smooth closed oriented Riemannian **surface**.

I am searching for a reference (or a sketch of proof) for the following inequality:

> $$ \int_M |  \nabla V|^2 \ge  \int_{M} \Ric(V,V)=\int_{M} K|V|^2, \tag{1}$$
>
> for every vector field $V \in \Gamma(TM)$, where $ \nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection, and the integration is against the Riemannian volume form. ($K$ is the Gauss curvature).

I guess some kind of Bochner identity is needed. I am also interested to know if this inequality holds for manifolds of higher dimensions.

BTW, specializing for the case of the round $2$-sphere, we get

$$ \int_{\mathbb{S}^2} |  \nabla V|^2 \ge  \int_{\mathbb{S}^2} |V|^2. \tag{2}$$

A proof of this specific case can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1041048/104576).

Comment: Question: I wish there was $|K|$ instead of $K$: can we have a non-vacuous inequality when the curvature is nonpositive?

Comment: That is a very good question. I also wondered about it, but I don't know the answer. I guess we can ask this as a separate question. As a starting point, we need to find out if there are non-zero parallel vector fields on a surface of negative curvature.

Comment: thank you. I'd really like to know, so maybe I'll ask the question. Regarding your starting point, unless I'm mistaken, a nonzero parallel vector field cannot exist on a surface, even locally, unless the curvature is zero. I guess you could see it as a consequence of this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16850/curvature-and-parallel-transport

Comment: I just remembered that a closed surface with negative Ricci curvature does not have non-zero parallel vector fields (see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607606/a-closed-manifold-of-negative-ricci-curvature-has-no-conformal-vector-fields). However, the flat Torus does have a non-zero parallel vector field. (e.g. $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_1}$) So, a Poincare-type inequality cannot hold on the flat Torus. However, we can still ask whether it holds on a surface with Ricci curvature that is everywhere negative...(Please let me know  if you ask this)

Comment: Yes, but cf my previous comment: "a nonzero parallel vector field cannot exist on a surface, even locally, unless the curvature is (everywhere) zero."

Comment: Yeah, you are right, so this gives us a chance. By the way, I don't see how this fact you mentioned on existence of parallel vector fields implying zero curvature follows form that mathoverflow discussion. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I think it's easier to use the known fact that if there exists a nonzero parallel vector field, then the manifold locally splits as $\mathbb{R} \times N$, and the metric is a product metric. In particular, any two-plane containing the vector has zero curvature. In the case of a surface, this just means the metric is flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably figured it out by now but since it's such a nice inequality I'll just point out that it follows from the identity in OP's other question :

[How to prove $\int_M-\text{Ric}(V,V)+ |\nabla V|^2 =\int_M \frac{1}{2}|L_Vg|^2-\big(\text{div}V\big)^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596693/how-to-prove-int-m-textricv-v-nabla-v2-int-m-frac12l-vg2)

Since $(\mathcal{L}_Vg)_{ij} = \nabla_iV_j + \nabla_jV_i$, on a manifold of dimension $n$ we find
$$\frac12|\mathcal{L}_Vg|^2 \geq \frac{1}{2n}|\text{trace}(\mathcal{L}_Vg)|^2 = \frac{2}{n}(\text{div}V)^2.$$
Thus the RHS of that identity is bounded below by $(\frac{2}{n} - 1)(\text{div}V)^2$ which is non-negative when $n \leq 2$.